# Getting only the keys but indexing producing error

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def swiss_pairings(self):
    players = self.player_standings()
    players_paired = []
    i = 0
    //  name = players.keys()[i]
    match_player = 1
    while match_player < range(len(players)):
        //  name_match_player = players.keys()[match_player]
        player_one_id = Player.objects.get(name=name)
        player_two_id = Player.objects.get(
            name=name_match_player)
        if self.has_played_before(player_one_id, player_two_id):
            match_player += 1
        else:
            self.report_match(player_one_id, player_two_id)
            players_paired.append(player_one_id.name, player_two_id.name)
            del players[name]
            del players[name_match_player]
            break
    return players_paired
```

The commented lines are producing that dictionaries are not indexed. What can be the replacement for those two lines?? I want only the "keys".

Comment: Of a `dict`?  You can see a dictionary view of the keys with [`my_dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys)

Comment: This will give me all the keys of that dictionary but I want like first and other keys one by one.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?